# Book series about a boy who learns from an elf that he has magic

Tags: story-identification, books

Can you help me identify a book series about a boy who doesn't know he has magic. A little elf tells him he has magic and that his dreams are real. I can't seem to remember the name and I've looked all over.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Why not have a look through this [handy guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can come up with any more info

Comment: Commenting here just for the update on when the name gets accepted.. Would love to read something like this